# Migrate SSRS reports to AZURE VM and without migrating On premise SQL Database. Is it possible?

Tags: sql-server, azure, reporting-services, migration, azure-vm

I have a SQL Server Database on Azure VM.I want to Migrate SSRS reports from on premise to Azure VM that would accesses the data from an existing on premise SQL Database that exists outside of Azure VM

Does anyone have any experience with this scenario, or could provide me some guidance on how to go about this.

Thanks,

Comment: Yes. This is hybrid cloud. You need a network connection from your Azure VM to your on prem SQL. You will need a network person to set this up. Do you have anyone who can help?

Comment: No, could you please guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same kind of request has been posted on Microsoft Q&A and an accepted answer has been given there by MSFT Customer Support Team.

I'm posting the link of the same thread below to help other community members on this platform.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/630657/on-premise-ssrs-migration-to-azure-vm.html